# OpenGL - Defining Model Matrix via instanced attribute

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

Im fairly new to OpenGL and I'm trying to use instancing to draw many 3D rectangles. I have currently positioned each 3d rectangle in a different position and they show properly.

Problem: I now want **each 3d rectangle to have a different rotation**, defined by me and pass it to the vertex shader. However when I do that, **The rectangles do not appear** on the screen anymore.

I'm not providing the complete code because it is fairly long. I'm only providing the important part and hoping that i'm making a silly mistake somewhere and you can point it out.

Here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 410 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 offset;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 3) in mat4 instanceMatrix;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;


out vec2 TexCoord;
void main()
{
    TexCoord = texCoord;
    gl_Position = projection * view * instanceMatrix * vec4(position + offset, 1.0f) ;

}
```

Here is the fragment shader:

```
#version 410 core

out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Here is the C++ code from where im sending the data:

```
// definition of models variable : std::vector<glm::mat4> models(0);


// Sending the Model matrix for each Rectangle
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, models.size() * sizeof(glm::mat4), &models[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLsizei vec4Size = sizeof(glm::vec4);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * vec4Size, (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * vec4Size, (GLvoid*)(vec4Size));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
    glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * vec4Size, (GLvoid*)(2 * vec4Size));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);
    glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * vec4Size, (GLvoid*)(3 * vec4Size));

    glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);

    // unfocus
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```